# Visual Studio 2013 Project with Multiple Property Sheets

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am working on a project using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 10. Basically I am writing a few MEX files using C++, and I'm using a few libraries that I use often: OpenCV and MATLAB's extern libraries. For each library, I have saved property sheets (.props files) with all of the necessary information. The gist of it is that I am trying to add both my opencv.props file and my matlab.props file to the project.

My current problem arises when I try to add multiple property sheets to the property configuration in "Property Manager." For each, I click "Add existing property sheet" and voila! I am supposed to get the proper settings. When I only use a single property sheet, everything works fine. When I try adding multiple sheets, only the most recent addition seems to be registering.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

I've pasted the contents of the .props files below since they're both pretty short and simple:

*matlab.props*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup />
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MATLAB_DIR)\extern\include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

*opencv.props*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" />
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <_PropertySheetDisplayName>OpenCV_debug</_PropertySheetDisplayName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(OPENCV_DIR)\..\..\include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link>
      <AdditionalLibraryDirectories>$(OPENCV_DIR)\lib</AdditionalLibraryDirectories>
      <AdditionalDependencies>opencv_calib3d$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_contrib$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_core$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_features2d$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_flann$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_gpu$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_highgui$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_imgproc$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_legacy$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_ml$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_nonfree$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_objdetect$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_ocl$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_photo$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_stitching$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_superres$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_ts$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_video$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;opencv_videostab$(OPENCV_VERSION)d.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <ItemGroup />
</Project>
```

Comment: Your property sheets have competing entries for the same setting. Some properties (like additional library references) can be set in each property sheet, while others (like the character set) cannot. Only specify properties that are specific to the respective libraries.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks! That makes sense. I've added the prop sheets to the question. Could you take a quick glance and tell me which fields are competing (they're both very short)? In each case it's only additional library reference that are set

Comment: Well, obviously the `<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>` competes between files, but how can I avoid that?

Comment: Future readers might find this a useful template: https://github.com/chappjc/MATLAB/blob/master/propertySheets/MATLAB.props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, properties in a property sheet overwrite previously set properties. To retain previous settings, you have to add them explicitly (using the *%(<prop>)* macro syntax).

For example, in your *opencv.props* file you need to replace

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MATLAB_DIR)\extern\include</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

with

```
<AdditionalIncludeDirectories>$(MATLAB_DIR)\extern\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)</AdditionalIncludeDirectories>
```

Apply the same changes to the `<AdditionalLibraryDirectories>` property; the `<AdditionalDependencies>` is already correct.